# Using $in on multiple fields in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am stuck on an issue related to `$in` in MongoDB, not getting the desired results.

Here is my MongoDB collection data for better visualisation

```
    [
        {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5aeaf7c73c3e9de82d91e439"),
        "companyID" : "4",
        "accounts" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5aeaf7c720262a1db759edf5"),
                "userID" : "1",
                "preferences" : [ 
                    {
                        "emailNotification" : true,
                        "smsNotification" : true,
                        "pushNotification" : false,
                        "webNotification" : false,
                        "lastUpdatedBy" : "SYSTEM",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5aeaf7c720262a1db759edf7"),
                        "preferenceID" : "6fbd6c-4c56-11e8-842f-0ed5f89f718b",
                        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-05-03T11:51:35.509Z"),
                        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-05-03T11:51:35.509Z")
                    }, 
                    {
                        "emailNotification" : true,
                        "smsNotification" : true,
                        "pushNotification" : false,
                        "webNotification" : false,
                        "lastUpdatedBy" : "SYSTEM",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5aeaf7c720262a1db759edf6"),
                        "preferenceID" : "6fb118-4c56-11e8-842f-0ed5f89f718b",
                        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-05-03T11:51:35.509Z"),
                        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-05-03T11:51:35.509Z")
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "__v" : 0
    },

    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5aeafe693c3e9de82d91e43a"),
        "companyID" : "5",
        "accounts" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5aeafe698b1d5f2057419c99"),
                "userID" : "1",
                "preferences" : [ 
                    {
                        "emailNotification" : true,
                        "smsNotification" : true,
                        "pushNotification" : false,
                        "webNotification" : false,
                        "lastUpdatedBy" : "SYSTEM",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5aeafe698b1d5f2057419c9b"),
                        "preferenceID" : "6fbd6c-4c56-11e8-842f-0ed5f89f718b",
                        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-05-03T12:19:53.436Z"),
                        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-05-03T12:19:53.436Z")
                    }, 
                    {
                        "emailNotification" : true,
                        "smsNotification" : true,
                        "pushNotification" : false,
                        "webNotification" : false,
                        "lastUpdatedBy" : "SYSTEM",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5aeafe698b1d5f2057419c9a"),
                        "preferenceID" : "6fb118-4c56-11e8-842f-0ed5f89f718b",
                        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-05-03T12:19:53.436Z"),
                        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-05-03T12:19:53.436Z")
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "__v" : 0
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5aeafe6d3c3e9de82d91e43b"),
        "companyID" : "6",
        "accounts" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5aeafe6d8b1d5f2057419c9c"),
                "userID" : "1",
                "preferences" : [ 
                    {
                        "emailNotification" : true,
                        "smsNotification" : true,
                        "pushNotification" : false,
                        "webNotification" : false,
                        "lastUpdatedBy" : "SYSTEM",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5aeafe6d8b1d5f2057419c9e"),
                        "preferenceID" : "6fbd6c-4c56-11e8-842f-0ed5f89f718b",
                        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-05-03T12:19:57.331Z"),
                        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-05-03T12:19:57.331Z")
                    }, 
                    {
                        "emailNotification" : true,
                        "smsNotification" : true,
                        "pushNotification" : false,
                        "webNotification" : false,
                        "lastUpdatedBy" : "SYSTEM",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5aeafe6d8b1d5f2057419c9d"),
                        "preferenceID" : "6fb118-4c56-11e8-842f-0ed5f89f718b",
                        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-05-03T12:19:57.331Z"),
                        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-05-03T12:19:57.331Z")
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5aeafe738b1d5f2057419c9f"),
                "userID" : "2",
                "preferences" : [ 
                    {
                        "emailNotification" : true,
                        "smsNotification" : true,
                        "pushNotification" : false,
                        "webNotification" : false,
                        "lastUpdatedBy" : "SYSTEM",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5aeafe738b1d5f2057419ca1"),
                        "preferenceID" : "6fbd6c-4c56-11e8-842f-0ed5f89f718b",
                        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-05-03T12:20:03.987Z"),
                        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-05-03T12:20:03.987Z")
                    }, 
                    {
                        "emailNotification" : true,
                        "smsNotification" : true,
                        "pushNotification" : false,
                        "webNotification" : false,
                        "lastUpdatedBy" : "SYSTEM",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5aeafe738b1d5f2057419ca0"),
                        "preferenceID" : "6fb118-4c56-11e8-842f-0ed5f89f718b",
                        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-05-03T12:20:03.987Z"),
                        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-05-03T12:20:03.987Z")
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("5aeafe778b1d5f2057419ca2"),
                "userID" : "3",
                "preferences" : [ 
                    {
                        "emailNotification" : true,
                        "smsNotification" : true,
                        "pushNotification" : false,
                        "webNotification" : false,
                        "lastUpdatedBy" : "SYSTEM",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5aeafe778b1d5f2057419ca4"),
                        "preferenceID" : "6fbd6c-4c56-11e8-842f-0ed5f89f718b",
                        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-05-03T12:20:07.062Z"),
                        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-05-03T12:20:07.062Z")
                    }, 
                    {
                        "emailNotification" : true,
                        "smsNotification" : true,
                        "pushNotification" : false,
                        "webNotification" : false,
                        "lastUpdatedBy" : "SYSTEM",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5aeafe778b1d5f2057419ca3"),
                        "preferenceID" : "6fb118-4c56-11e8-842f-0ed5f89f718b",
                        "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-05-03T12:20:07.062Z"),
                        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-05-03T12:20:07.062Z")
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "__v" : 0
    }]
```

**What I am trying to get from the data.**
I am trying fetch each company's user preferences based on a companyID & userID, but for multiple company and multiple users, not for a single one.

Say for an example I have this input Data `[`userID:2`,`companyID: 6`]` and [`userID:1`, `companyID:4`]

The **output** based on above added documents data, should be

```
    [
        {
            "userID":2,
            "companyID":6,
            "preferences":[] // the preferences from that db
        },
        {
            "userID":1,
            "companyID":4,
            "preferences":[] // their respective preferences array
        }
    ]
```

The above is the desired output, Now my approach for solving this

**Approach**

- I am getting input parameters in the form array of objects liks this

  ```
  input_json = [{
          "userID":2,
          "companyID":6
      },
      {
          "userID":1,
          "companyID":4
      },
  ]
  ```
- After getting the input JSON, I am making two different arrays users array, company's array, `user_array` will hold all the userIDs, `company_array` will hold all the companyIDs like this

  ```
  user_array = input_json.map((elem)=>elem.userID) // which will hold all the company ID

  //For the above input_json, the value of `user_array` would be 
    //  `user_array: [2,1]`


  company_array = input_json.map((elem)=>elem.userID)
  //For the above input_json, the value of `company_array` would be 
    //  `company_array`:[4,4]
  ```
- After I got both the values of userIDs & companyID separately, I am firing a query on MongoDB using the $in to match id from array

  ```
  db.collection.find({
      userID:{
             $in:user_array 
      },
      accounts.companyID:{
          $in:company_array
      }
  })
  ```
- I am not getting the desired results, I want  the userID and companyID to be used as an unique key for getting the data.

But what is happening is it is matching the userID in `user_array` and companyID in `company_array`.However, I want both `userID` and `companyID` to be checked for getting the data.

Any help will be much apreciated :)

Comment: Pretty sure you just mean `{ $or: arr }` here. That would be the AND of each "set" of conditions, where as `$in` applies all different sets of combinations over two values. Show documents you would expect to match if you are still unsure

Comment: Hi Sunil Lulla; to make it really clear what you are trying to do, and what is going wrong, could you paste in an example of the query results you're getting back, and an example of the query results you want to get?

Comment: @VinceBowdren Have a look, I added the desired output

Comment: Have a look, I just added the desired output. @NeilLunn

Comment: So if one field is in the top of the document and another is in an array with `"listOfFields"` then how are you supposed to know which one searches the root and which searches the array? In all honesty, the real problem here is you have real data you are not showing us. Trying to express it in an abstract way is simply not coming across in a clear manner. Better to show something more representative of your actual data and a real request, otherwise it's likely any response you get will also be very wrong.

Comment: @NeilLunn Please go through this link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sunil-lulla/stackoverflow/master/question

Comment: I have added my schema there, Have a look

Comment: So what you are "really" asking here is that you have an array of input with `userID` and `companyID` values which will be unique to a document in combination. So if you have 4 array entries then each should return the document those conditions match but of course you want all 4 documents matching and not just one. Or of course if the combination is not "unique" then everything it matches. But it's still **always** the `userID` and `companyID` combination. Right?

Comment: Because frankly man, that's nothing like what you are asking the the typed question above. Your github link comes of sooo much clearer and should in fact the the phrasing of the question here.

Comment: You also need to clear up whether you are asking something like `[{ "companyId": "6", "userId": "1" },{ "companyId": "6", "userId": "3" }]` and what you expect to happen there. So really your question should include that `company` document, and a different one and then those two conditions as well as one condition for the other document and what you expect as a result from that. Or of course if no two array entries can have the same company value, then say so. You're question really needs to be much clearer than it is presented here. Changing things like that will make it clearer.

Comment: Yes I am expecting  ` [{ "companyId": "6", "userId": "1" },{ "companyId": "6", "userId": "3" }]` this only as my input JSON, and output would be the the preferences of user haveing companyID as 6 and userID as 1 and so on. I am updating my answer as well. @NeilLunn

Comment: @NeilLunn I have updated the question for better understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just expanding a little on your sample to include the "possible" case that your request array actually asks for multiple users from the same company.

The essential "query" condition is simply a remapping of the input array and using it within an [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) query argument. which comes out like:

```
{
  "$or": [
    {
      "companyID": "6",
      "accounts.userID": "3"
    },
    {
      "companyID": "6",
      "accounts.userID": "2"
    },
    {
      "companyID": "4",
      "accounts.userID": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

That will match you the "documents", but the respective "user" information is contained within the `"accounts"` array. In order to retrieve only those items we need to apply a [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) condition to simply keep those array entries matching the criteria. Then it's really just a matter of using `$unwind` on the remaining array content and a little document reshaping to put in the desired output format with [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/).

The whole generated statement would come out like:

```
Company.aggregate([
  { '$match': { 
    '$or': [
      { companyID: '6', 'accounts.userID': '3' },
      { companyID: '6', 'accounts.userID': '2' },
      { companyID: '4', 'accounts.userID': '1' }
    ]
  }},
  { '$addFields': { 
    accounts: { 
     '$filter': { 
        input: '$accounts',
        cond: {
          '$or': [ 
            { '$and': [
              { '$eq': [ '$companyID', '6' ] },
              { '$eq': [ '$$this.userID', '3' ] }
            ] },
            { '$and': [
              { '$eq': [ '$companyID', '6' ] },
              { '$eq': [ '$$this.userID', '2' ] }
            ] }, 
            { '$and': [
              { '$eq': [ '$companyID', '4' ] }, 
              { '$eq': [ '$$this.userID', '1' ] }
            ] }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { '$unwind': '$accounts' },
  { '$project': {
    userID: '$accounts.userID',
    companyID: 1,
    preferences: '$accounts.preferences'
  }}
])
```

The content of the [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) for the query and the additional form of [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/or/) for the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) are basically generated from the input array like so:

```
    let query = {
      $or: input.map(({ userID, companyID }) =>
        ({ companyID, 'accounts.userID': userID }))
    };

    let condition = input.map(({ userID, companyID }) =>
      ({ "$and": [
        { "$eq": ["$companyID", companyID] },
        { "$eq": ["$$this.userID", userID] }
      ]})
    );
```

And then used as arguments within the rest of the pipeline construction, which is mostly static. Note the usage within the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) as `"cond"` requires the "aggregation logical operators" which return a boolean value based on what they test. So they are different from the query operators in form an function.

The same "pairing" applies to each `$or` condition so that both the `"companyID"` value as well as the current `"userID"` value in the accounts array are considered when looking for a match with that combination. Within the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) it is important to check the `"companyID"` from outside the array whilst also checking the current array element.

The reason we cannot do this with standard [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) projection is essentially because of the [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) condition in the query. There is the additional constraint of "multiple matches" added here for demonstration, but because of the [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) in the query, MongoDB cannot determine which of the "set of conditions" actually satisfied element match position for any individual document anyway.

So it does not really matter if you want "one" user to match from each company or "many", since the same aggregation filter needs to be applied in order to extract the correct "user(s)" detail anyway.

A full listing for demonstration follows:

```
const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/test';

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug',true);

let input = [
  {
    "userID": 3,
    "companyID": 6
  },
  {
    "userID": 2,
    "companyID": 6
  },
  {
    "userID": 1,
    "companyID": 4
  }
];


// non-strict for testing
const Company = mongoose.model('Company', new Schema({},{ strict: false }));

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri);

    // Clean data to actually be matching strings
    input = input.map(({ userID, companyID }) =>
      ({ userID: userID.toString(), companyID: companyID.toString() }));


    let query = {
      $or: input.map(({ userID, companyID }) =>
        ({ companyID, 'accounts.userID': userID }))
    };
    log(query);

    let condition = input.map(({ userID, companyID }) =>
      ({ "$and": [
        { "$eq": ["$companyID", companyID] },
        { "$eq": ["$$this.userID", userID] }
      ]})
    );
    log(condition);


    let result = await Company.aggregate([
      { "$match": query },
      { "$addFields": {
        "accounts": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$accounts",
            "cond": { "$or": condition }
          }
        }
      }},
      { "$unwind": "$accounts" },
      { "$project": {
        "userID": "$accounts.userID",
        "companyID": 1,
        "preferences": "$accounts.preferences"
      }}
    ]);

    log(result);

    mongoose.disconnect();
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    process.exit()
  }


})()
```

And this gives output like:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5aeaf7c73c3e9de82d91e439",
    "companyID": "4",
    "userID": "1",
    "preferences": [
      {
        "emailNotification": true,
        "smsNotification": true,
        "pushNotification": false,
        "webNotification": false,
        "lastUpdatedBy": "SYSTEM",
        "_id": "5aeaf7c720262a1db759edf7",
        "preferenceID": "6fbd6c-4c56-11e8-842f-0ed5f89f718b",
        "createdAt": "2018-05-03T11:51:35.509Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-05-03T11:51:35.509Z"
      },
      {
        "emailNotification": true,
        "smsNotification": true,
        "pushNotification": false,
        "webNotification": false,
        "lastUpdatedBy": "SYSTEM",
        "_id": "5aeaf7c720262a1db759edf6",
        "preferenceID": "6fb118-4c56-11e8-842f-0ed5f89f718b",
        "createdAt": "2018-05-03T11:51:35.509Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-05-03T11:51:35.509Z"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5aeafe6d3c3e9de82d91e43b",
    "companyID": "6",
    "userID": "2",
    "preferences": [
      {
        "emailNotification": true,
        "smsNotification": true,
        "pushNotification": false,
        "webNotification": false,
        "lastUpdatedBy": "SYSTEM",
        "_id": "5aeafe738b1d5f2057419ca1",
        "preferenceID": "6fbd6c-4c56-11e8-842f-0ed5f89f718b",
        "createdAt": "2018-05-03T12:20:03.987Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-05-03T12:20:03.987Z"
      },
      {
        "emailNotification": true,
        "smsNotification": true,
        "pushNotification": false,
        "webNotification": false,
        "lastUpdatedBy": "SYSTEM",
        "_id": "5aeafe738b1d5f2057419ca0",
        "preferenceID": "6fb118-4c56-11e8-842f-0ed5f89f718b",
        "createdAt": "2018-05-03T12:20:03.987Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-05-03T12:20:03.987Z"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5aeafe6d3c3e9de82d91e43b",
    "companyID": "6",
    "userID": "3",
    "preferences": [
      {
        "emailNotification": true,
        "smsNotification": true,
        "pushNotification": false,
        "webNotification": false,
        "lastUpdatedBy": "SYSTEM",
        "_id": "5aeafe778b1d5f2057419ca4",
        "preferenceID": "6fbd6c-4c56-11e8-842f-0ed5f89f718b",
        "createdAt": "2018-05-03T12:20:07.062Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-05-03T12:20:07.062Z"
      },
      {
        "emailNotification": true,
        "smsNotification": true,
        "pushNotification": false,
        "webNotification": false,
        "lastUpdatedBy": "SYSTEM",
        "_id": "5aeafe778b1d5f2057419ca3",
        "preferenceID": "6fb118-4c56-11e8-842f-0ed5f89f718b",
        "createdAt": "2018-05-03T12:20:07.062Z",
        "updatedAt": "2018-05-03T12:20:07.062Z"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Which shows we only returned the matching company and user detail combinations from the documents.

---

> **NOTE** Not sure if with the input sample you gave it was **"intentional"** that the values are given as "numeric" and not as "strings", where of course they are actually "strings" in the data it needs to match to. There's a simple line of code which is converting the numeric values to strings, which of course is not necessary where both your input types and stored types match already.
>
> Also whilst mongoose would typically "cast" these values under normal query operations to whatever was in the schema, this **does not** happen with aggregation pipelines. Any conditions you apply for matching within the aggregation pipeline operations requires **"you"** to cast values to the correct type yourself.
>
> Mongoose does not do this because it cannot make the "presumption" during an aggregation pipeline stage that the data presented at the time is in the same state as what the schema knows about. Aggregation operations are typically about "reshaping documents", and for this reason "schema" does not apply here.

Comment: Thanks, it is working perfectly as I wanted.                                                           I faced a bit of issue in your solution because of `$addFields`, because it got added in version 3.4, and I was using 3.2. However, I solved it by ugrading it to 3.6 :)